# How to publish a GML file as a Web Feature Service (WFS)?

Tags: geoserver, open-source-gis, wfs, gml

I am interested in publishing a GML file as a WFS. I don't want to use a database like PostgreSQL. What would be the rough steps I need to do for that?
I like to use open source software (geoserver). I don't have much experience. I am just looking for a rough guide what kind of software I should look into and which step follows which step..

Comment: It would be helpful if you can expand upon what you know so far, what you've looked for, any promising leads you have, etc.  It will give people a better idea how to help you out.

Comment: Typically you wouldn't hold the data to be provided in a WFS as GML in GML, you would store the data in database.  Then you configure the WFS service to provide the GML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I good tutorial on how to set up a wfs in GeoServer can be found here:
http://www.gistutor.com/geoserver/11-beginner-geoserver-tutorials/36-setting-up-a-wfs-in-geoserver-using-a-shapefile.html

The steps are for a shapefile. However I assume they are very similiar for a GML File.

Comment: The link does not provide instructions for how to enable WFS.

Comment: Yeah it does. At the bottom it says: "Your shapefile is now set up for use as a WFS. To preview your layer, click on “Layer Preview..."

Comment: Once you create a workspace you have to edit it and check the WFS checkbox for it to be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

As geoserver is fully compliant to WFS, including the *"Transactional WFS"* level of service. You can provide a running instance with GML to write to its storage with any WFS-T client. More info about this capability of geoserver is available here:

https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/index.html

If you need an open source WFS-T ETL tool, you can use the current daily builds of HALE 3.0.0 (the release version of 2.9.0 doesn't yet have this capability):

https://github.com/halestudio/hale