# Deploy GeoPackage file as a web service

Tags: qgis, geoserver, geopackage

I have a .gpkg GeoPackage from [here](https://github.com/facebookmicrosites/Open-Mapping-At-Facebook/wiki/Available-Countries) unzpped and stored on a cloud server. I want to make it possible to use as one of the URL based geo-services listed in QGIS (WMS, GeoNode etc) : So people can zoom in to their area of interest and selectively pull down just the data they need without having to download all 8 GBs of it. And it has to be in vector form with the metadata intact - can't be as raster tiles. What would be a good way of going about making such a deployment? I don't have prior experience in deploying geo-servers etc, sorry if this is sounding very naive.

Additional: I want to do this with docker and persistent volumes so that if there is any conversion/indexing to do, I can do it once and after that the whole thing can be shifted and redeployed anywhere else without having to repeat work.

Sharing bits and pieces I'm finding; would be great to cobble together a flow that starts with a .gpkg and ends with a QGIS-ready URL.

- [Import gpkg into PostGIS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-import-geopackages-into-postgres-postgis-database)
- [Docker PostgreSQL Tutorial with Persistent Data](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3gnMSyX-XM) (video)

Note for mods: this is not the same as a [similar sounding question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/333128/sharing-geopackage-for-collaborative-work-web-ftp-cloud) which is asking how to edit a .gpkg in the cloud. Another [similar question about GML](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53048/how-to-publish-a-gml-file-as-a-web-feature-service-wfs) as the answers giving broken links.

Comment: I fixed the links for you in the duplicate

Comment: Thanks. Still don't get it. Is this forum only for the people who don't need it?

Comment: did you try looking at the answer for the previous question - it solves your problem! If you truly believe that your question is different then you need to [edit] it to make that clear. Otherwise this site would be populated with about 10 questions asked time after time.